# How to install python cairo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycairo

I am new to python3. I have created the virtual environment. I try to install the pycairo package using pip command. I need install python cairo. Please see the below info

```
pip install git+http://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/pycairo
Downloading/unpacking git+http://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/pycairo
  Cloning http://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/pycairo to /tmp/pip-0c_foz-build
  Running setup.py egg_info for package from git+http://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/pycairo
    cairo >= 1.10.2  Successful

Installing collected packages: pycairo
  Running setup.py install for pycairo
    cairo >= 1.10.2  Successful
    building 'cairo._cairo' extension
    gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/python3.2mu -c src/cairomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-3.2/src/cairomodule.o
    src/cairomodule.c:22:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /home/nyros/Desktop/NewWeb/venv/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-0c_foz-build/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-lo0egc-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /home/nyros/Desktop/NewWeb/venv/include/site/python3.2:
    cairo >= 1.10.2  Successful

creating py3cairo.pc

creating src/config.h

running install

running build

running build_ext

building 'cairo._cairo' extension

creating build

creating build/temp.linux-i686-3.2

creating build/temp.linux-i686-3.2/src

gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/python3.2mu -c src/cairomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-3.2/src/cairomodule.o

src/cairomodule.c:22:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /home/nyros/Desktop/NewWeb/venv/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-0c_foz-build/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-lo0egc-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /home/nyros/Desktop/NewWeb/venv/include/site/python3.2 failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-0c_foz-build
Storing complete log in /home/nyros/.pip/pip.log
```

But I got the error. Please solve my problem. Thanks

Comment: Could you post the results of command `find /usr/include -name Python.h`. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for reply. the result is **/usr/include/python2.7_d/Python.h
/usr/include/python2.7/Python.h
/usr/include/python2.6/Python.h
/usr/include/python2.6_d/Python.h**

Comment: So, something is wrong with the compilation process done by PIP. If you look at the `gcc` invocation, you will see `-I/usr/include/python3.2mu`. Your `Python.h` is present in many directories, but not that pointed to `gcc`. The strange thing is that you're traying to compile it against **Python3.x**, while your system has headers only for **Python 2.x**...

Comment: Thanks, I have solved my problem using sudo apt-get install python3-dev. And it is attached the Python.h file to python3.2mu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this may solve your problem:

`sudo apt-get install python3-dev`

But I cannot guarantee that this will work 100% :-)